# NAudio recording output stream

Tags: c#, naudio

First I initialize it

```
WaveIn waveInStream = new WaveIn();
waveInStream.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 2);
waveInStream.BufferMilliseconds = 36000000;  

waveInStream.DeviceNumber = 0;

waveInStream.DataAvailable += WaveInStream_DataAvailable;
waveInStream.RecordingStopped += WaveInStream_RecordingStopped;

WaveFileWriter wave_writer = new WaveFileWriter(full_file_path, waveInStream.WaveFormat);
```

On  waveInStream.StartRecording(); I get an exception - BadDeviceId calling waveInOpen.
And I see WaveIn.DeviceCount = 0;
But I don't need an actual input device like mic, I want to record sound I generate and pass to a sound card output.
How should I set waveInStream to do it?

Comment: If you generate sound yourself then you need an output device, not input devices

Comment: I generate the sound in an output device, but record it in an input device. WaveOut has no StartRecording/StopRecording methods.

Comment: You already have the data so there’s no need for any devices then. If you want to save it into a wav file just use the `WaveFileWriter` and give it your data

Comment: I see. But I generate notes using other (Sanford) library. May I generate notes with NAudio?

Comment: If you’re not controlling the generation yourself but just giving an output device to another library you can always create an output device yourself that just takes the data and saves it and also gives it to an actual output device. It doesn’t require that many methods. Or you could possibly use `WasapiLoopbackCapture`

Comment: How do I do that?  It looks quite complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

I did like I was suggested

```
MMDevice mm_dev;

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OutputDevice.DeviceCount > 0)
    {
        outDevice = new OutputDevice(0);

        MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        //here I see my sound card
        mm_dev = enumerator.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.All, DeviceState.Active)[0];

         loopback_capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(mm_dev);
         loopback_capture.DataAvailable += Loopback_capture_DataAvailable;
         loopback_capture.RecordingStopped += Loopback_capture_RecordingStopped;
         
         wave_writer = new WaveFileWriter(full_file_path, waveInStream.WaveFormat);
    }
}

private void Loopback_capture_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
     wave_writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
}
```

But on **loopback_capture.StartRecording();** I get -

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

What do I miss?